# Git: Cannot get MAIN and DEVELOP back into sync

Tags: git, github, merge

**Starting scenario**
`main` and `develop` had the same code, and the same last two commit messages, but different commit hashes (presumably due to some rebasing), and in GitHub, `develop` said "2 commits ahead, 2 commits behind main."
My enterprise repo is set up so that force pushing to develop and main aren't allowed, and GitHub only allows "Merge commit," "Squash and merge," and "Rebase and merge," not "fast-forward merge."

**What I did**
Locally, I pulled both branches, then I rebased develop on master, and pushed `develop.` It said everything was up to date. I created a PR, GitHub said they could be automatically merged, and chose Merge Commit. But now `main` has the merge commit and `develop` doesn't, and GitHub says `develop` is one commit behind `main.` Understandable, but it gives me no way to bring it up to date. I try to do a back-merge from `main` onto `develop` and use "Squash and merge" even though there's nothing to squash. This *should* be a fast-forward merge, but after I merge it now, now GitHub is saying that `develop` is

> One commit ahead, 3 commits behind `main`

How am I ever supposed to get these back in sync if GitHub won't do a simple fast-forward merge? Can I do it locally without needing to force push?

Answer (score 3):

I think the solution here is human engineering: you need to change your expectations. "In sync" for two branches means that the *state of the project* is the same in both branches. The way to confirm that is with a simple `git diff branch1 branch2`. If that is the case, and that's the goal, then don't worry, be happy.

You should *not* expect that one branch will not be behind the other, because after a merge, one branch is *always* ahead of the other, for the trivially obvious reason that it contains the merge commit and the other doesn't. If two branches consisted of identically the same commits, they would be the *same branch* and one of them should probably be deleted.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but at the point of merging develop into master, I would expect them both to point to the exact same commit at that point in time. Of course then develop will get ahead the next time it gets a commit. The thing I'm saying is that Github is saying there always needs to be a PR *even after merging* because the commit hashes are different, because it won't just do a fast-forward merge.

Comment: "but at the point of merging develop into master, I would expect them both to point to the exact same commit at that point in time" And I'm telling you to stop expecting that. After a true merge, the two branches can _never_ point to the exact same commit, as I explained in my answer. (They can after a fast-forward but a fast-forward is not, in fact, a true merge.) Basically you are now just making me repeat my answer.

Comment: @redOctober13 I **super strongly** suggest that you start using [`gitk`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75924423/23118) as you every single day git history visualization tool. It will help you better understand how the history is composed and connected.

Answer (score 0):

> But now main has the merge commit and develop doesn't, and GitHub says develop is one commit behind main.

You can locally fast-forward-merge main into development at this point.

> I try to do a back-merge from main onto develop and use "Squash and merge" even though there's nothing to squash.

When merging main (or develop etc. – the long-lived branches) back into some side branch, never squash. Keep the whole history instead. This feature on GitHub is only to squash a *topic branch* that's being merged to main, so that lots of individual commits from the topic branch don't pollute the log of main.

---

As matt said in their answer, as long as main is merged into development, it really doesn't matter if this is a fast-forward merge or not. That is, going with GitHub's merge is totally fine. Merge commits will be there, but they don't affect future development in any way.

Comment: I guess what I want is for Github to say both branches are in sync, like `git log` would locally. If I did a merge commit from develop to main, then once that was in, I did `git rebase main` from develop, they would be exactly in sync, which is what I want to be the case before more changes happen on develop.

Comment: After you merge develop into main, do `git merge main` from develop locally. This will be fast forward and you don't need to force push.