# How to read the lines (graph) in in the git graph window

Tags: git, graph, repository

I am learning about visual studio and trying to understand the graphs in the graph window. I know that the light blue dots are commits and the grey dots are merges. In the first picture below i have checked out my development branch i my local ropo, and that makes it my active branch. In the first picture below i under stand that i have branched out of my development branch, and created a feature branch, made a comit in that branch and the merged my feature branch in to my development branch. So far so god. I the last picture i am still in my local development branch, i can see that there are several lines, but what do they represent? Are they all a version of my developmnet branch or are some of them feature branches? I so how do i dertime which ones are featue branhes and which one is my development branch. Please help me understand picture number two.

Sincerely
Christian

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkOFJ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOFfQ.jpg

Comment: I think you might want to go through a semi quick tutorial: https://learngitbranching.js.org/
It is easier than having someone copy paste an explanation from somewhere.

Comment: Please update the question to show the images directly inline. I do not know what tool creating those, however you will in any case do very good in start using [`gitk --all &`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75924423/23118) as your every day main git history visualization tool.