# Git what can I do when git merge does not create files that have been deleted in master branch

Tags: git, merge

Having trouble on git merge. Here is what I did.

1. Created new branch feat.
2. Made several commits on feat and master.
3. Accidentally merged feat on master and pushed.
4. Did (revert -m 2) and pushed.
5. Made several commits on feat and master.
6. Merged feat on master on purpose to release new features.

When I did 6. many files are not created by merge.
It seems like files that has been changed after revert get created by merge.
But I guess files that are not modified since revert are not getting created by merge.
Is there any git commands that I can use at this situation?

This is a year of work. I can't add one by one or just overwrite files without checking conflicts.

Comment: Did you miss Step 7 or is it a typo? In Step 4, I think you should have run `git revert -m 1` on `master`. With `-m 2`, it discarded changes from `master`.

Comment: The right way to fix an accidental merge is to undo the merge, i.e., change the commit history, provided that you can afford to rewrite history. That requires that you *know* what the bad history looks like and how you want the good history do look like. Do you?

Comment: edited typo. Maybe I remember wrong. Anyway I am not sure if I did -m 2 or -m 1 but git removed all the files from branch feat.

Comment: The doc [how to revert a faulty merge](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) could help. You can find the link in the `-m` section of the `git revert` manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classical error.

What have happened is that all the commit which was merged in during your first commit now is considered as part of the history of `master` which means they wont be considered in the second merge.

You can fix it in a couple of ways.

###### Revert the revert

This will result in a single commit which contains all the changes originally removed by the first revert.

###### Copying the branch history with force rebase

If you look at the log of `feat` and find the point where you created it from `master` you can basically copy the branch with `git rebase -f <commit-id>` where commit-id should be the commit before the first commit which was part of `feat`.

A graphical git history tool would be very useful for finding the correct commit.
Try the command `gitk --all &` (it is included in most installations of git)

Since the copied history aren't part of the history of `master` the merge should work without problems. (or you might have to revert your second merge first to avoid conflicts between the original version of `feat` and the new version.)

Comment: thank you. I will try this on my next duty day.

Comment: `git merge-base feature/xxx master` would identify this common ancestor.

Comment: @YSC I'm afraid that wont work. The entire problem the original poster is facing is actually that `git merge-base` in this specific case is the commit in `feat` which is just before the accidental merge.

Comment: indeed @Kim; one would need to find the merge-base from a prior commit here

Comment: @MinPoke I alsovery strongly recommend [using gitk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75924423/23118). And with regards to force pushing, you absolutely should use the safer alternative to `--force`, see the `forcepush` alias [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76984332/23118).

Comment: I tried merge-base but I don't know why it did nothing. Both of reverting the revert commit and rebasing worked. Thank you all. I guess I am going to solve this by reverting the revert commit.