# All data on main branch was changed to a later commit, losing all data, possible to get back data?

Tags: git

On date 06/01 I made a push to git. I worked on files for a month without adding, committing, and pushing and a colleague of mine somehow lost all of the files that were worked on by pulling all data from an earlier commit and all future commits are now on this path. Is there any way to get the files back even though they were never added, committed or pushed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accidentally reverted to master, lost uncommitted changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147680/accidentally-reverted-to-master-lost-uncommitted-changes) i.e. No i.e. use a backup

Comment: It sounds like there was a forced push involved here. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76984332/23118) for some details on what the challenges with that is and how to recover. And tip for recovery (either in your or the other repository, I did not quite get where commits were missing), `git reflog` will display references to those "lost" commits for some time until git cleans up unreferenced commits, and even better use `gitk --reflog` for a graphical overview (in addition to [using `gitk --all`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75924423/23118) as your everyday history visualizer).

Comment: `I worked on files for a month without ...` **You MUST change this behaviour!** Beginners in git are sometimes afraid of checking in things, but that is the wrong mindset - *you should be afraid of not checking in changes*. Commit time gaps should be in minutes, sometimes hours, extremely seldom days, newer weeks, and under absolutely no circumstances whatsoever months. NEVER! In fact [you should never be more than 2 minutes away from checking in and going home](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aWiwDdx_rdo)).